# Mover File para Lixeira JAVA

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop, delete

Ola, tem alguma forma de eu mover um File para a lixeira ao inves de excluílo definitivamente?

```java
 File f = new File("um caminho com um arquivo top aki);
 f.delete(); //retorna um true caso consiga deletar, e isso ocorre na hora.
 f.deleteOnExit();  //procedimento void que deleta o arquivo no fechamento da aplicação.
```

Comment: Parece que tem uma API nova no Java 9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#moveToTrash-java.io.File-

Comment: Para fazer isso seria java.awt.Desktop.moveToTrash(f) ?? porque mesmo com java 10 no meu netbeans não esta funcionando...

Comment: estou tentando baixar o nb 11 pra ver se resolve... ja retorno com o resultado..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugerido pelo @cezar a utilização do moveToTrash() deu certo.

Para ver a versão do java basta ir no cmd e verificar que o mesmo é java 9 ou posterior

`java -version`

O NetBeans utilizado foi o 11.